# How to use forkjoin to return combined responses of two independent API calls in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, fork-join

I have two independent api calls. Below is the code for two api calls:

```
public getLendingType(partyId: string): Observable<{ lendingType: string, partyId: string }> {
    return this.customerRepositoryService.getCustomer(partyId).pipe(
        map((customer: ICustomer) => {
          return { lendingType: customer.LendingType, partyId: partyId } ;
        })
      );
  }

  private getPartyType(partyId: string): Observable<{ partyType: string}> {
    return this.partyRepositoryService.getParty(partyId).pipe(
      map((party: IParty) => {
        return  { partyType: party.PartyType };
      })
    );
  }
```

As you can see both api call is independent from each other. At this point I want to use forkjoin to combine their responses and return the combined result. This is where I got stuck. The code I have written for this part is below:

```
  public getPartyTypeAndLendingType(partyId: string): Observable<{ partyType: string, lendingType: string, partyId: string }> {

        return forkJoin([this.getLendingType(partyId), this.getPartyType(partyId)]).subscribe ( result => {
            return { partyType: result[1].partyType, lendingType: result[0].lendingType, partyId: result[0].partyId }
        })
  }
```

but I think I am missing something for which still I am getting compiler error like the image below:

[image]

and hovering over the compiler error it showing below messages:

```
Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<{ partyType: string; lendingType: string; partyId: string; }>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.ts(2740
```

How to achieve this and make this piece of code working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling `.subscribe()` your function returns a `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`.

To transform the result of the API calls use a `.pipe()` with `map()`. This way your function will return an Observable.

```
return forkJoin([
    this.getLendingType(partyId), 
    this.getPartyType(partyId)
]).pipe(
  map(result => 
    ({ partyType: result[1].partyType, lendingType: result[0].lendingType, partyId: result[0].partyId })     
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are having an error because at the method signature, you are saying that you will return an `Observable` but what you are returning instead is a `Subscription`. There is an easy fix, you were really close though :)

```
public getPartyTypeAndLendingType(partyId: string): Observable<{ partyType: string, lendingType: string, partyId: string }> {
  const lendingType = this.getLendingType(partyId);
  const partyType = this.getPartyType(partyId);

  return forkJoin([lendingType, partyType]).pipe(
    map(result => ({
      partyType: result[1].partyType,
      lendingType: result[0].lendingType,
      partyId: result[0].partyId
    }))
  );
}
```

Instead of subscribing within the method (which is fine for some purposes, really depends on your needs), we are now using the `map` operator to map the response. Now the subscription part, should be done by the caller.

Comment: thank you, both answer served my purposes and to the point but unfortunately I can make only one answer as correct one.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad that it helped :) Regarding the marked answer, I'm OK with it, he deserved, both the answers were correct, and he replied sooner! It's all good :)